# Optimizing google script that grabs Instagram post data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, instagram

Over the past few days/weeks I've been working on a Google Script that imports Instagram data in to a spreadsheet. So far I've successfully managed to grab things like follower, following data, engagement rate and amount of posts and daily changes.

I'm now working to find a way that allows me to grab the data on a post-by-post level and update the data daily. But since i'm really a novice in programming. I'm doing it in a very inefficient way and I don't have an idea how to update existing rows.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Get Date field filled
function insertPostData(sheetName, instagramAccountName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"), Post1Comment(instagramAccountName)]); 
  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"), Post2Comment(instagramAccountName)]); 
  Utilities.sleep(200);
}; 



//Write post1 comments to Sheet
function Post1Comment(username) { 
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1", totalCount = 0;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      totalCount += parseInt(JSON.parse(response).user.media.nodes[i].comments.count);
     return totalCount;
}}

//Write post2 comments to Sheet
function Post2Comment(username) { 
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1", totalCount = 0;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
      totalCount += parseInt(JSON.parse(response).user.media.nodes[i].comments.count);
     return totalCount;
}}
```

And this I would need to for 12 posts (which you can freely grab from the https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1 url. Thinking about the fact that I want to grab multiple objects (post date, likes, comments, media id,..) from each post doing it this way would be really inefficient...

Can anybody help find the right direction to do this more efficient?

Comment: What is the difference between `Post1Comment` and `Post2Comment` ?

Comment: Use a for loop? Store the accounts you monitor in one sheet, read those in as part of the called function's initialization, then use a `for` loop to call your post getter function on each name. Inside the post getter, fetch their link, then append a row with the relevant data to the logging spreadsheet. Once you're easily importing data, then worry about only importing "new data", by adding checks to the sheet for a given "post id", or minimizing calls to the spreadsheet functions through batch methods, etc.

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues in my answer, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()`? Recently, this method was added. This method can fetch several requests.

At `fetchAll()`, the requests can be executed using an array with the requests. The response from `fetchAll()` is an array. And the indexes in the array of response are corresponding to those of the requested array. I thought that this can be used for your situation.

When this method is used for your situation, the modified script is as follows.

#### Flow :

- Create the request array.
- Fetch using the created requests.
- Convert the retrieved data to import to Spreadsheet.
- Import the converted data.

#### Modified script :

```
function insertPostData(sheetName) {
  var userNames = [
    "instagramAccountName1",
    "instagramAccountName2",
    "instagramAccountName3",
    ,
    ,
  ]; // Please input instagramAccountNames here.

  var requests = userNames.map(function(e){return {"url": "https://www.instagram.com/" + e + "/?__a=1", "method": "get"}});
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var totalCounts = [];
  for (var j in response) {
    var totalCount = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
      totalCount += parseInt(JSON.parse(response[j]).user.media.nodes[i].comments.count);
    }
    totalCounts.push([date, totalCount]);
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, totalCounts.length, totalCounts[0].length).setValues(totalCounts);
}
```

#### Reference :

- [fetchAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry. If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify.