# Use URL status code function in array formula

Tags: google-apps-script

The following Google Apps script gets the HTTP status of a URL. But when I try to use it in an arrayformula, it returns a "limit exceeded" error. Is there something I need to modify in the script to make this work? Thank you

```
function getStatusCode(url){
    var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'followRedirects': false
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   return response.getResponseCode();
  }
```

edit: second method, needs adjustment

```
function getStatusCode(url){
   var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var foo = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, options);
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(foo);
   return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

Comment: use `fetchAll` method instead

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to... Would you mind showing me how?

Comment: @Julien Reaux Is this document useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests

Comment: @Tanaike yes and no. I had looked at this and tried using fetchAll using the second method I pasted in the edit of my original post. But I think I'm not doing it right.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization You should modify the entire function to accept arrays `urls` instead of `url`. Then make a batch call with `fetchAll` for all urls in your spreadsheet(say, A2:A200) in a single function (like `=getStatusCodes(A2:A200)`) . Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49162731